# HTML Doctype differences

Tags: asp.net, html

I've been creating a website in ASP.net using the default template in vs2010 with a Site Master.
I'd been getting strange results where an image with a span under it would not line up as they always had whitespace between them.
I spent hours looking at the markup and finally created a plain .htm file out of desperation and copied my html into it. To my suprise this actually worked so after another hour of comparing the differences I noticed that the template creates the site.master with

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Whereas it creates the .htm file with

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Can anyone explain the difference between Strict (Which causes errors in my layout) and Transitional (Which means the layout is as I expect) and if using Transitional in my aspx pages will cause me any future difficulties down the road?

I do have a warning in VS that states

```
validation (xhtml 1.0 transitional): element 'h2' cannot be nested within element 'span'
```

I guess this could be the source of the error when using Strict but I'm not sure how to get around it.

Edit: Here is the block in question that is causing the error

```
<a href="http://somelink.com">
    <img src="Images/test.png alt="Test" />
    <span class="Styling for hovering">
        <h2>
            Test
        </h2>
        <p>
            This Is A Test
        </p>
    </span>
</a>
```

I'm trying to create a link that is activated by the image and the text below it.  I want to hold the text in a container. That containers background will change when it's hovered over. I also set a fixed size for the span. This is the main reason I need some kind of container around them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer?

Traditional = Allow old school [deprecated](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/elements-deprecated)  HTML tags like <font>, <center>, <s> and be very forgiving about things in HTML that we're not supposed to do anymore.

Strict = Use css to replace most of those tags, and enforce the rules the way the W3C defines.

The long answer: You can read through the 25+ page [specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.2) for each of the HTML spec types from the W3C, but if you're creating new pages you should probably try to stick to **XHTML 1.0 Strict** since it's the hip cool wave of the future and Transitional gives some graphic designers the heebie jeebies. :)

[W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) has a pretty good breakdown of what each type means more or less:

> **XHTML 1.0 Strict** This DTD contains all HTML elements and attributes, but does NOT INCLUDE presentational or deprecated elements
>   (like font). Framesets are not allowed. The markup must also be
>   written as well-formed XML.
>
> **XHTML 1.0 Transitional** This DTD contains all HTML elements and attributes, INCLUDING presentational and deprecated elements (like
>   font). Framesets are not allowed. The markup must also be written as
>   well-formed XML.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of which DOCTYPE you use you cannot place a block level element (`<h2>`) inside of an inline element (`<span>`). That's why you're getting that error. Since `<span>` is typically used for styling I suspect you could remove that `<span>` and use CSS to style the `<h2>` to appear however you desire.

Comment: Thanks John - I've added the suspect html to my question.  I am indeed trying to style the background of h2 and p so the background changes when you hover over it.  Could you tell me what to use instead of span?

Comment: Use  `<div>`. It can contain other block level elements. It's the block level version of `<span>`.

Comment: Then it moans Div can't be nested within A. That's why I switched to span but obviously that's not correct either.